# How to pass value from first yield to next ones in ES6 generator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

I searched for real cases ES6 generators and didn't find proper explanation. I am trying to understand this first **Promise** scenario.

Let's say we have 2 rest apis: **getUser** and **getUserComments**

We wan't to create a linear code structure avoiding nested **then** callback functionalities. So ...

**Define mocked apis**

```
function getUser () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       return setTimeout(function() { resolve({id: 1, label: 'John'}); }, 200);
    });
}

function getUserComments(userId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      return setTimeout(function() {resolve({comments: 'comments', userId: userId}); }, 200);
    });
}
```

**Define generator**

```
function* generator () {
  yield getUser();
  yield getUserComments(userId); // userId represents data from first request / first yield how should I pass it ?!
}

var g = generator();
var first  = g.next(1);
var second = g.next(2);
```

How can I get the response from first yield (yield getUser()) and pass it to the next yield (yield getUserComments(userId)) ?

Comment: Fix your code, it's invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just assign yielded result to variable:

> The next() method also accepts a value which can be used to modify the internal state of the generator. A value passed to next() will be treated as the result of the last yield expression that paused the generator. (*From [MDN, Advanced generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Advanced_generators)*)

Then since you are dealing with Promises it makes sense to use async/await to unwrap it to value.

Try this (I corrected setTimeout parameters a bit):

```
async function getUser() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 0, {
      id: 1,
      label: 'John'
    })
  })
};

async function getUserComments(user) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 0, {
      ...user,
      comments: 'comments',
    }, 'userComments');
  });
}

function* generator () {
  const user = yield getUser();
  yield getUserComments(user);
}

(async function () {
  const g = generator();
  const user = await g.next().value
  const comments = await g.next(user).value

  console.log(comments)
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

At some pointing the promise would have to be awaited or chained (`then`). Is the goal to prevent chaining altogether or only in the implementing code? Otherwise the generator itself could do the chaining so the calling code doesn't have to:

```
function* generator () {
    const u = getUser(), c = u.then(userId => getUserComments(userId));
  yield *[u,c];
}
```

Example:

```js
function getUser () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       setTimeout(function() { resolve({id: 1, label: 'John'}); }, 200);
    });
}

function getUserComments(userId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {resolve({comments: 'comments', userId: userId}); }, 200);
    });
}


function* generator () {
 const u = getUser(), c = u.then(userId => getUserComments(userId));
  yield *[u,c];
}


(async function(){
 var g = generator();
  var first  = await g.next().value;
  var second = await g.next().value;
  console.log(first, second);
})();
```

For the calling code it doesn't matter which promise is resolved/awaited first. Although of course the chain has to be completed for previous steps if awaiting a later step. e.g.:

```js
function getUser () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       setTimeout(function() { resolve({id: 1, label: 'John'}); }, 200);
    });
}

function getUserComments(userId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {resolve({comments: 'comments', userId: userId}); }, 200);
    });
}


function* generator () {
 const u = getUser(), c = u.then(userId => getUserComments(userId));
  yield *[u,c];
}


(async function(){
 var g = generator();
  var prom  = g.next().value;  
  var second = await g.next().value;
  
  console.log(await prom, second);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `next` with a parameter and get it using `yield`. Example :

```
function* generator () {
  var userId = yield getUser();
  yield getUserComments(userId); // userId represents data from first request / first yield how should I pass it ?!
}

var g = generator();
var first  = g.next();
var userId = getUserId(first);
var second = g.next(userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to get the result you required. Without `.then()`, I cannot get the result of `getUser()`

```js
function getUser () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       return setTimeout(function() { resolve({id: 1, label: 'John'}); }, 200);
    });
}

function getUserComments(userId) {
    console.log(userId)
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      return setTimeout(function() {resolve({comments: 'comments', userId: userId}); }, 200);
    });
}

function* generator () {
  var userId = yield getUser();
  yield getUserComments(userId); // userId represents data from first request / first yield how should I pass it ?!
}

var g = generator();
   
(async function(){
  var first = await g.next();
  var userId = await first.value.then((res)=>{ return res.id });
  g.next(userId);
})();
```